# How to count rows with values (non-unique values) in a group?

Tags: ssrs-2008

In SSRS, I have a table grouped by student id with some details based on semesters.  The grouped part of the report includes things like test scores.  That is, one student would have one score for such-and-such test.  The user wants a summary showing "how many students have a score for such-and-such test?"  When I try to count rows that have a value for that column, it multiplies the count by the number of details (semesters).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CountDistinct** to count the unique student IDs.

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!STUDENT_ID.Value)
```

> Returns a count of all distinct values from the specified expression.

-- Visual Studio Expression Description

Comment: Thank you but that's not really the problem.  I have students who do or do not have a test score.  That's in the grouped part.  In the detail section, they have a row for one semester or two rows if they attended two semesters.  I need to count how many students have test scores.  Currently, if the student has two semesters in the detail section, the count for him comes back as 2.  It needs to be 1.